# Every two $n$-sheeted Coverings of $S^1$ Are Isomorphic

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

In [Prove that two $n$-sheeted covering space of $S^{1}$ are isomorphic.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848672/prove-that-two-n-sheeted-covering-space-of-s1-are-isomorphic) it was asked whether the Blaschke product and $z^n$ are isomorphic. I am wondering are these two coverings the only $n$-sheeted cover of $S^1$? If not, does every two coverings are isomorphic? I have difficulty to find the homeomorphism to prove every two coverings are isomorphic. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Theorem 1:* Given any connected, [locally path-connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_connected_space#Definitions_and_first_examples),
> [semi-locally simply
> connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-locally_simply_connected#Definition)
> pointed space $(X,x)$ and any subgroup $H$ of $\pi_1(X,x)$ there
> exists a connected covering $p\colon (\widetilde X,\widetilde{x})\to
>  (X,x)$ such that $p_*\pi_1(\widetilde X,\widetilde x)=H$. Moreover, if
> $q\colon (\widetilde Y,\widetilde{y})\to (X,x)$ is another connected
> covering such that $q_*\pi_1(\widetilde Y,\widetilde y)=H$, then there
> is a homeomorphism $\varphi\colon (\widetilde Y, \widetilde y)\to
> (\widetilde X, \widetilde x)$ so that $p\circ \varphi=q$.

For proof, see Proposition 1.36. on page 66 of [Hatcher's Algebraic Topology](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf).

> *Theorem 2:* If $p\colon (\widetilde X,\widetilde x)\to (X,x)$ is covering such that $\widetilde X$ is path-connected, then cardinality
> of $p^{-1}(x)$ is the same as index of the subgroup
> $p_*\pi_1(\widetilde X,\widetilde x)$ in $\pi_1(X,x)$.

For proof, see Proposition 1.32. on page 61 of [Hatcher's Algebraic Topology](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf).

---

Since $\Bbb S^1$ is a connected manifold, it is locally path-connected, semi-locally simply connected. Now, $\pi_1(\Bbb S^1,1)=\Bbb Z$ and the *only* subgroup of $\Bbb Z$ with index $n$ is $n\Bbb Z$ for any integer $n\geq 1$. Also, $p:\Bbb S^1\ni z\longmapsto z^n\in \Bbb S^1$ is an $n$-fold covering for integer $n\geq 1$ and if $q\colon Y\to \Bbb S^1$ is any other connected $n$-fold cover of $\Bbb S^1$ then there is a homeomorphism $\varphi\colon Y\to \Bbb S^1$ such that $\big(\varphi(y)\big)^n=q(y)$ for all $y\in Y$.

Note that the covering $\Bbb S^1\ni z\longmapsto z^{-n}\in \Bbb S^1$ is related to the $\Bbb S^1\ni z\longmapsto z^{n}\in \Bbb S^1$ via the homeomorphism $\Bbb S^1\ni z\longmapsto z^{-1}\in \Bbb S^1$. In other words, up to homeomorphism, there is exactly one $n$-fold connected covering map of $\Bbb S^1$.

Answer (score 2):

For $n\geq 1$, $\mathbf S^1$ has (up to isomorphism) only one (regular) covering of index $n$. This is because $\pi_1\left(\mathbf S^1\right)\simeq\mathbf Z$ has only one (normal) subgroup of index $n$, namely $n\mathbf Z$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more the relation of subgroup and $n$-sheeted covering?

Comment: @LaurencePW a good reference would be Massey's book "A Basic Course in Algebraic Topology". I also like Bredon's "Topology and geometry". You should take a look at Bredon page 154, theorem 8.1. Basically there is a one to one correspondence between subgroups of the fundamental group and (isomorphism classes of) covering spaces. This correnpondence sends normal subgroups to regular covering spaces (bur for the circle every subgroup is normal).

Comment: Thank you for your references, I will take a look on those books